# How to type Mui v5 Chip color prop with value as object key

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

How can I type MUI Chip prop `color` if actual value comes from an object? At the moment I use `any` but it is not a good option. And one more question, is as `keyof typeof CHIP_COLORS` correct way for typing?

```
import { Chip, Stack } from "@mui/material";

const DATA = [
  {
    id: 2,
    status: "success"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    status: "finished"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    status: "error"
  }
];

const CHIP_COLORS = {
  finished: "primary",
  error: "error",
  success: "success"
};

export default function App() {
  return (
      <Stack
        sx={{gap: 5}}
      >
        {DATA.map(({ id, status }) => {
          return (
              <Chip
                color={CHIP_COLORS[status as keyof typeof CHIP_COLORS] as any}
              />
          );
        })}
      </Stack>
  );
}
```

**Codesandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-breeze-s4vpfk?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create custom types.

```
type eventType = "finished" | "success" | "error";
type colorType = "primary" | "error" | "success" | "default" | "secondary" | "info" | "warning" | undefined
```

your data type:

```
const DATA:{ id:number, status:eventType }[] =  [
  {
    id: 2,
    status: "success"
  },
  ...
```

chip color type:

```
const CHIP_COLORS: { [key in eventType]: colorType } = {
  finished: "primary",
  error: "error",
  success: "success"
};
```

component:

```
{DATA.map(({ id, status }) => {
        return (
         <>
           <Chip color={CHIP_COLORS[status]} />
          </>
        );
 })}
```

[image: Edit wild-cloud-6q050i]

Comment: Just one more question. Should I always list all color types in colorType which Chips accept or can I list just list three?

Comment: if you want, you can. the only condition is `colorType` should be  includes the colors ("primary" etc.) e.g: `colorType = "primary" | "secondary"` correct but `colorType = "primary" | "asd"` is not valid